# Run artisan command (make: migration) in my controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to run artisan command through controller.
i need to create migration file and define attribute in migration file
all the work perform through Controller.
**according to my idea OR i want this type of solution**
first create migration file and write through controller then run migrate command.

Comment: Run migrate in the controller  **Okay possible**.  First, create the migration file **but why?**

Comment: Why does this need to be done through a migration? Just run the `Schema::table....` command directly in the controller

Comment: @apokryfos how to run Schema::table.... command directly in the controller.....i think like this Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
    $table->string('email');
});

Comment: yes that should work

Comment: Yeah Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel [Schema Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema) can help you. Here is the code to create test table.

```
Schema::create( 'test', function ( $table ) {
            $table->string( 'name' );
} );
```

Schema::table will work if you have created the table first. here is the code for that

```
Schema::table( 'test', function ( $table ) {
            $table->string( 'name' );
        } );
```

and this is the class you need to use.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```